# Azure Authentication with AAD & Google in a Xamarin Forms Project not Redirecting back to app after Authorized

Tags: android, azure, authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Azure Active Directory

Google+ Auth

Xamarin Forms, PCL (NuGet 2.4.0.282)

Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.0.0 & 4.0.2

After I successfully Login my phone does not return to my app. I have two test phones and one emulator, they display different info, after login.

Phone 1 (AAD Auth):
[image]

Phone 1 (Google Auth it greys out and just keeps "loading")
[image]

Phone 2 (AAD and Google Auth):
[image]

Emulator (AAD and Google Auth):
[image]

I have done everything I found here on Stack OverFlow, that makes sense and seems to be applicable to current versions of NuGets.
This person seems to be having a similar issue to me but with Google Log in
[Azure not redirecting after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705721/azure-not-redirecting-after-login)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705721/azure-not-redirecting-after-login)

I have tried integrating code into my project. And then I input my Azure info into Xamarin's sample: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/TodoAzureAuth

And I get the same results. I have tried both AAD and Google+ Auth. After login it just stays at the browser. So I feel like the client side code has to be correct. But I cant find any mess up on my Azure server code. I have tried this with projects that have a C# and Node.Js backend.(For one of my projects) My ALLOWED EXTERNAL REDIRECT URLS is ToDoList53172://easyauth.callback and in my AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.xamarin.sample.TodoAzure">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="TodoAzure" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.RedirectUrlActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="ToDoList53172" android:host="easyauth.callback" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

OLD:
And I don't feel like I should post all the other code. It is all in the Xamarin sample project posted above. If people think I should I will.
NEW: 
I am adding more code just to help people out. I did not want to overload, but better to have all the info in one place. So here is my MainActivity.cs Code

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Android.Webkit;

namespace TodoAzure.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "TodoAzure.Droid",
        Icon = "@drawable/icon",
        MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
        Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light")]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity, IAuthenticate
    {
        MobileServiceUser user;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
            App.Init((IAuthenticate)this);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public async Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync()
        {
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                if (user == null)
                {
                    // The authentication provider could also be Facebook, Twitter, or Microsoft
                    user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, Constants.URLScheme);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        CreateAndShowDialog(string.Format("You are now logged in - {0}", user.UserId), "Logged in!");
                    }
                }
                success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CreateAndShowDialog(ex.Message, "Authentication failed");
            }
            return success;
        }

        public async Task<bool> LogoutAsync()
        {
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                if (user != null)
                {
                    CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie();
                    await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LogoutAsync();
                    CreateAndShowDialog(string.Format("You are now logged out - {0}", user.UserId), "Logged out!");
                }
                user = null;
                success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CreateAndShowDialog(ex.Message, "Logout failed");
            }

            return success;
        }

        void CreateAndShowDialog(string message, string title)
        {
            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.SetMessage(message);
            builder.SetTitle(title);
            builder.SetNeutralButton("OK", (sender, args) => { });
            builder.Create().Show();
        }
    }
}
```

And Like I said above I have tried this with AAD as well. The code above is for Google.

Here is my Azure Auth setup
[image]

Here is the info I get after logging in with "https://todolistjbb.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad" and then visiting 
"https://todolistjbb.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me"
[image]

I feel like I have tried SO many things. I have recorded 66.68 hours working on just trying to get Authentication in my app.... please... someone tell me what I am doing wrong! I am losing it over here :'(

Answer (score 2):

The way to solve this problem is do not start with a capitalized letter for your Url Scheme. It took me over 2 weeks to figure it out. I don't think this sis written anywhere, but I am sure it is. 
So yeah to fix this i switched "ToDoList53172" to "todolist53172" 
That's it... Oy vey!

Comment: Dude, you are saved my life in 2020! Give me your address, I'll send you a gold medal :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using the [Server-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow) provided by [Azure App Service authentication/authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview). Since you are using the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client >= 4.0.0, for your mobile client, you would leverage the following code snippet for logging via the server-flow:

```
var user = await client.LoginAsync(this, provider, "{url_scheme_of_your_app}");
```

Details you could follow [Add authentication to the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-users#add-authentication). Moreover, you need to [Add your app to the Allowed External Redirect URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-users#redirecturl).

Based on the error message from your phone 2:

> todolistjbbservice://easyauth.callback/#authorization_code=xxxxx

It seems that you did not configured the **Authorized Redirect URI** correctly. For the Azure Active Directory provider, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication) for registering your Web App / API or Native application. For the Google provider, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication).

After correctly configured your preferred identity provider(s), you need to add your app to the Allowed External Redirect URLs:

- Log into Azure Portal, choose your App Service
- Click the Authentication / Authorization, 
  enter `ToDoList53172://easyauth.callback` in the Allowed External Redirect URLs, and save your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know I posted a ton of info, but in it I do say that I already set my Allowed External Redirect URL to ToDoList53172://easyauth.callback

"My ALLOWED EXTERNAL REDIRECT URLS is ToDoList53172://easyauth.callback and in my AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:"

I did not list my code for MainActivity.cs because it is all exactly what the example project is in my link. But yes my LoginAsync looks exactly like what you wrote.

I will edit my post with more screenshots of my setup. Sorry for not being super clear I did not want to have a super long post.

Comment: Your mobile backend is trying to redirect the user to `todolistjbbservice://easyauth.callback/#authorization_code=xxxxx`. Since you have configured the Allowed External Redirect URLs, I assumed that you need to follow the **Authorized Redirect URI** part in my answer and follow the tutorials to check the **Redirect URI**  when you configure your login provider.

Comment: Oh sorry. That screenshot was just from one of my many, many, many attempts. That was the correct Authorized Redirect URIs at that time. I will update screenshots to show the updated ones tomorrow. But just know that the todolistjbbservice was registered as todolistjbbservice://easyauth.callback. I have just lost count of how many versions I have done, and my pictures span all of them. sorry for the mix up

Comment: For a simple way, I would recommend you directly access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/{provider-name e.g google or aad}` via the browser and try to check your login provider has been successfully configured. After logged, you could access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` to retrieve your logged user info.

Comment: Yeah I have done that too. I feel like I have followed so many tutorials and have read so many forum posts.
Here is the results. And again sorry if all the urls don't match up. I am in the process of getting all screenshots from one version of the project.
[ScreenShot of .auth/me page](https://ibb.co/g4oxr6)

Comment: I have updated the original post with all updated screenshots so all are from one version of the project. I hope that helps. Sorry I didn't do it from the start

Comment: Based on your mobile app endpoint, I used Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client v 4.0.2  and I just tested the Windows 10 app project  and found that it could work as expected. After v4.0.0, the login experience has changed under the client library. Details you could check [Azure Mobile Apps Managed SDK Change Log](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). Or you could downgrade the client library to v3.1.0 to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Hey Bruce, So because of your comment I figured out the problem. I made a UWP version and ran it and it worked. I did take notice that when I was adding the Protocol that it said I could not start my Url Scheme with a capital letter. I though "omg if it was because I have been using a capital this whole time I am gonna be so pissed!" I switched the Url Scheme in the AppManifest from "ToDoList53172" to "todolist53172" annnndddd it worked... 2 weeks of work lost because of a capitalized letter. Ahhh Syntax! you gotta love it....

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved this issue. I plan to check this issue on my working environment today.